# substitution for calling main

Tags: java, loops

I have this problem where I am trying to start the game over if the user says yes, and I always do it by calling main(), but my teacher insists that there are better ways. How do I start the program without calling the main. I assuming you have to use loops but I'm not sure how to use it for this problem.

```
        //import library
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    //file name
    public class GuessingGame
    {
        //Main method, throws input and output error.
        public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
        {
            //inputs for random number and switch statements
            Scanner inRn = new Scanner (System.in);
            Scanner inSw = new Scanner (System.in);

            //variables for the loop, random number, character, counter and input
            int guess=0;
            int rnd;
            int num;
            char decision;

        //random number generator
        Random random = new Random();
        rnd = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

        //loops the user input for the guess
        while (true){
            try{
                //prompt the user
                System.out.println(" Please guess a number between 1-100. Press 0 to give up.");
                num = inRn.nextInt();
            }
            //catches input errors 
            catch (Exception e){ 
                System.out.println("You can only enter numbers!");
                inRn.next();
                continue;
            }

        //if statements
        if (num==0) 
        {
            //when user types '0' it ends the program
            System.out.println("You gave up after " + guess + " try(s)  .... Closing program ...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (num>rnd) 
        {



                System.out.println("The number is too big!"); 
                guess++;
            }
            else if (num<rnd)
            {
                //prints 'too small', adds to counter 'guess'
                System.out.println("The number is too small!"); 
                guess++;
            }
            else 
            {
                //prints correct, adds to counter, dsiplays # of guesses and ends loop
                System.out.println("You guessed the right number!!: " + rnd); 
                guess++; 
                System.out.print(" # of guesses: " + guess + " -");

                //loops the case untill correct input is chosen either 'Y' or 'N'
                while(true){

                    //prompt the user if they want to play again
                    System.out.println(" Would you like to play again? <Y/N>");
                    decision = inSw.nextLine().charAt(0);

                    //switch statements
                    switch (decision) {
                        case 'Y':
                        case 'y':    
                            //calls main, basically restarts the game
                            GuessingGame.main(args);     
                            break;

                        case 'N':
                        case 'n':
                            System.out.println("Bye!");
                            //exits the program completely
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;

                        default: 
                            //if incorrect input, this prints
                            System.out.println("Please enter a Yes or No <Y/N>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on do/while loops.  You will probably want to enclose most of your `main` method inside one.

Comment: @David Wallace but a do while loop is same as a while loop in the sense that it does the same thing, how is a do while loop supposed to change the program, im already using while for whole main.

Comment: No, really, you're not.  You're using `while` after the random number has been chosen.  You want to include the random number generation inside the part that gets repeated in the big loop.  My reason for suggesting a `do/while` loop is that you will always run the body of the loop at least once, so you may as well put the check for whether to repeat the loop at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: @user3505212 Calling the main method recursively from inside the while(true) loop will eventually cause a StackOverflowError exception to be thrown.

Comment: Yes, but not before the user gives up and goes home.

Answer (score 1):

I Remember being in programming class and my teacher told me to avoid the while(true) statements.

Anyway, there is a loop specifically designed for this kind of behavior,  it's called a [do-while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).  Calling the main method from with in the main method is called a recursive call.  They have their places, they can do jobs other loops just can't.

The problem here is that each method call has it's own local variables, when you call the main again, it still remembers all the results from the last game, and every game before that.  Which doesn't seem so bad, esp if you use that information later.  The bigger problem is that recursive loops cannot be called an infinite amount of times like the for or while loops.  The local variables stored for each call to main are stored on a stack.  When the stack fills up you get an [StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).  If you want to see this happen make a main method like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    main(args);
}
```

Here is an example of a do-while loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
char decision;
do{
    //game code ...
    do{
        System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? (y,n): ");
        decision = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }while(!(decision == 'y' || decision == 'n'));
}while(decision == 'y');
```

Some cool Recursion uses:

[Factorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/10/iteration-vs-recursion-in-java/)

[Fibonacci sequence](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-recursion/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining what a StackOverflowError is.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've moved the game logic to a new `play()` method. This method returns a `boolean` to indicate whether the user wants to keep playing at the end of the game. I've used a `do...while` loop in the `main` method to start the game at least once and then check the return value of the `play()` method to decide whether to keep playing.

This way the program will end gracefully without forcing it to exit using `System.exit` methods. It will also not make use of the recursive method calling inside the `while(true)` loop which will eventually end up in a `StackOverflowError` exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean keepPlaying = false;

    do {
        keepPlaying = play();
    } while (keepPlaying);
}

private static boolean play() {
    //inputs for random number and switch statements
    Scanner inRn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inSw = new Scanner(System.in);

    //variables for the loop, random number, character, counter and input
    int guess = 0;
    int rnd;
    int num;
    char decision;

    //random number generator
    Random random = new Random();
    rnd = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

    //loops the user input for the guess
    while (true) {
        try {
            //prompt the user
            System.out.println(" Please guess a number between 1-100. Press 0 to give up.");
            num = inRn.nextInt();
        } //catches input errors 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You can only enter numbers!");
            inRn.next();
            continue;
        }

        //if statements
        if (num == 0) {
            //when user types '0' it ends the program
            System.out.println("You gave up after " + guess + " try(s)  .... Closing program ...");
            return false;
        } else if (num > rnd) {

            System.out.println("The number is too big!");
            guess++;
        } else if (num < rnd) {
            //prints 'too small', adds to counter 'guess'
            System.out.println("The number is too small!");
            guess++;
        } else {
            //prints correct, adds to counter, dsiplays # of guesses and ends loop
            System.out.println("You guessed the right number!!: " + rnd);
            guess++;
            System.out.print(" # of guesses: " + guess + " -");

            //loops the case untill correct input is chosen either 'Y' or 'N'
            while (true) {

                //prompt the user if they want to play again
                System.out.println(" Would you like to play again? <Y/N>");
                decision = inSw.nextLine().charAt(0);

                //switch statements
                switch (decision) {
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'y':
                        // User wants to keep playing
                        return true;
                    case 'N':
                    case 'n':
                        System.out.println("Bye!");
                        //exits the program completely
                        return false;
                    default:
                        //if incorrect input, this prints
                        System.out.println("Please enter a Yes or No <Y/N>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher right, you don't have to call the main again, just enhance your algorithm, and you will get a better code. Perhaps something like this :

```
//import library
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

//file name
public class GuessingGame {
    // Main method, throws input and output error.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // inputs for random number and switch statements
        Scanner inRn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inSw = new Scanner(System.in);

        // variables for the loop, random number, character, counter and input
        int guess = 0;
        int rnd;
        int num = -1;
        char decision = 'Y';

        // random number generator
        Random random = new Random();
        rnd = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

        // loops the user input for the guess
        do {
            if (num != rnd) {
                try {
                    // prompt the user
                    System.out
                            .println(" Please guess a number between 1-100. Press 0 to give up.");
                    num = inRn.nextInt();
                }
                // catches input errors
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("You can only enter numbers!");
                    inRn.next();
                    continue;
                }

                // if statements
                if (num == 0) {
                    // when user types '0' it ends the program
                    System.out.println("You gave up after " + guess
                            + " try(s)  .... Closing program ...");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (num > rnd) {

                    System.out.println("The number is too big!");
                    guess++;
                } else if (num < rnd) {
                    // prints 'too small', adds to counter 'guess'
                    System.out.println("The number is too small!");
                    guess++;
                } else {
                    // prints correct, adds to counter, dsiplays # of guesses and
                    // ends loop
                    System.out.println("You guessed the right number!!: " + rnd);
                    guess++;
                    System.out.print(" # of guesses: " + guess + " -");
                }
            } else {
                // prompt the user if they want to play again
                System.out.println(" Would you like to play again? <Y/N>");
                decision = inSw.nextLine().charAt(0);

                // switch statements
                switch (decision) {
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                    System.out.println("Bye!");
                    // exits the program completely
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                case 'y': 
                    rnd = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    // if incorrect input, this prints
                    System.out.println("Please enter a Yes or No <Y/N>");
                }
            }
        } while (decision != 'N' || decision != 'n');
        inRn.close();
        inSw.close();
    }
}
```

Why this code is much better, IMHO it will be because of these :

1. It only use one loop, while your's use 2 loops.
2. It didn't call the main function again, which will trigger another process to start in memory, and probably will cause a memory leak.
3. It close the input scanner, while yours didn't.

Hope this will brighten your day, I'm sorry if there are any mistake. Thanks & Regards.